# Can't open a time series in my working directory

Tags: r, time-series

just started with R for my master program. In my first exercise for "Time Series Analysis" we need to load two given time series. When i try to load i always get the same error.

I try to load the data by the following code :

```
library(tseries)
wine <- read.ts("wine.tsm", freq = 12, start = c(1980, 1)) 
lake <- read.ts("lake.tsm", freq = 1, start = 1875)
```

For both data files i recieve the error :
Error in count.fields(file, sep = sep, skip = skip) :
  cannot open file 'wine.tsm': No such file or directory

How can i fix this?

Comment: IHave you checked the working directory `getwd()`  if the file is not in the working directory, specify the path `read.ts("/path/to/wine.tsm")`

Comment: Use `list.files()` also to check what is in your current working directory

Comment: To avoid the issue, an interactive option would be `file.choose()`